# Is Gmail for business still free

Tags: google, email

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Free Google Apps could not be found](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/30735/free-google-apps-could-not-be-found)

I remember a while back Google offered free email to businesses, where you host your email with them and still use emails like me@mydomain.com. I can't seem to find this now. I only see a paid subscription. Is it still available? where?

> **Related:**
>   [Free Google Apps could not be found](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/30735/free-google-apps-could-not-be-found)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's still available for 10 user accounts. [Get started with Google Apps for free](http://www.google.com/apps/intl/en/group/index.html)

Comment: I can see free 10 user account, this is not there at the link you provided Cheten S.

Comment: I mean I can't see

Comment: Looks like Google has changed the page elements. You can still get that option on clicking the `Pricing` tab or use this direct link - https://www.google.com/a/cpanel/standard/new3?hl=en&source=gafb-pricing-tabletop-en

Comment: No longer true. Here's one article about it. http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2012/12/google-apps-no-longer-free-for-small.html?m=1

Answer (score 10):

Google Apps for Business is no longer free—only a free trial of 30 days.

[Source](http://googleenterprise.blogspot.ca/2012/12/changes-to-google-apps-for-businesses.html).

Answer (score 3):

Google Apps stops accepting free sign-ups

> Starting today for all new customers:
>
> Individuals wishing to use Google’s web apps like Gmail and Google
>   Drive should create a free personal Google Account, which provides a
>   seamless experience across all of our web services on any device.
>
> For Businesses, instead of two versions, there will be one. Companies
>   of all sizes will sign up for our premium version, Google Apps for
>   Business, which includes 24/7 phone support for any issue, a 25GB
>   inbox, and a 99.9% uptime guarantee with no scheduled downtime.
>   Pricing is still $50 per user, per year.

http://googleenterprise.blogspot.tw/2012/12/changes-to-google-apps-for-businesses.html